# How to activate a flex application so the user doesn't have to click inside it to start getting keyboard events

Tags: apache-flex

My Flex application is heavily keyboard-oriented. It uses 100% of the browser window and I'd like the user to be able to start using it immediately -  as soon as it loads.

However, it seems that the application is only first "activated" (i.e. the activate event fires) when the mouse clicks somewhere inside it, which is very inconvenient for my keyboard-heavy app.

Can I force an activation of my app at some point during/after it loads?

I hope I don't have to display some silly "click inside to activate" overlay every time the page loads...

**Addendum**

In certain browsers ([cough] Chrome [/cough]) the focus is lost whenever the user switches away from the browser (or even touches the address bar) and is *not* regained when switching back. So the solution has to take in consideration not just the first focus when the page loads but also "re-focusing".

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK the problem occurs only in certain browsers like Firefox. You can change that behaviour with a little bit of JavaScript. Edit your `index.template.html` and add the following code snippet within the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocusToSwf() {
        var swf = document.getElementById('${application}');
         if (swf) swf.focus();
    }
</script>
```

Flex Builder will replace the `${application}` placeholder when it compiles your application.

Change the `<body>` tag so that your new function gets called when the browser finished loading the document:

```
<body onload="setFocusToSwf()">
```

Comment: Actually, FireFox is being a good boy compared to Chrome. In FireFox, at least, one the application gets focus it regains it if you switch away from the browser and back. In Chrome, however, every time you touch anything outside the SWF you have to click back on it. The onload solution, I suspect, won't solve this.

Comment: Indeed, the solution works in FF but doesn't work at all in Chrome, for some reason.

Comment: I didn't notice this until now. It looks like there's no solution for Chrome right now. The workaround mentioned in http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27868 doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. People reading this question should "star" that issue in Chrome to get it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use it on creation to get it work in chrome:

```
ExternalInterface.call("function() { 
    var app = document.getElementById('App');
    if(app) {
        app.tabIndex = 0;
        app.focus();
    }
}");
```

Ravi Sankar Gonthina